# CSV copy script error reporting in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I've got this script which copies files listed in a csv recursively from a main folder. The copying aspect of the script works perfectly. However, I now want to add some error detection functionality. The "if" loop I have added below doesn't work as I would like. I have added a fake file to my csv list for testing purposes, and the script reports that all files have copied successfully, even though one of the files doesn't exist. Could someone suggest how I can get the script to report the file(s) it has not successfully found/copied from the csv and specify the file names? 
EDIT ** As there are 4000+ files listed in the CSV, I would like the script to print a summary of any copy failures at the end of the script, rather than for each files copied during the process. This would make it easier to identify/summarize any issues.

```
while IFS=, read -r file rest
do
find $sourcefolder -name "${file}" -exec cp '{}' $destfolder \;
done < $csv
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
echo "All files from CSV copied succesfully"
else "File from CSV not copied as not found"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code returned by `find` has nothing to do with whether any files were found. It will only return a failure code if the command itself failed to run. What you are looking for is something like:

```
while IFS=, read -r file rest
do
  find $sourcefolder -name "${file}" -exec cp '{}' $destfolder \;
  ## Check if the file was copied
  [[ -e "$destfolder/$file" ]] || echo "File $file was not copied"
done < "$csv"
echo "Finished"
```

That way, the script will tell you about any files that weren't successfully copied.

If you only want to print the error at the end of the script, you can save the bad file names in a variable and print it after the loop has finished:

```
while IFS=, read -r file rest
do
  find "$sourcefolder" -name "$file" -exec cp '{}' "$destfolder" \;
  ## Check if the file was copied
  [[ -e "$destfolder/$file" ]] || badfiles=$(printf "%s\n%s" "$file" "$badfiles")
done < "$csv"

## Check if all the files were correctly copied
if [[ -z "$badfiles" ]]; then
        echo "All files were succesfuly copied."
else
        printf 'Some files were not copied:\n%s\n' "$badfiles"
fi
```

You can also extend this to avoid overwriting files with the same name:

```
while IFS=, read -r file rest
do
  find "$sourcefolder" -name "$file" -print0 |
    while IFS= read -d '' -r filepath; do
     c="";
     while [[ -e "$destfolder/$file$c" ]]; do
       ((c++))
     done
     cp "$filepath" "$destfolder/$file$c"
  done
  ## Check if the file was copied
  [[ -e "$destfolder/$file" ]] || badfiles=$(printf "%s\n%s" "$file" "$badfiles")
done < "$csv"

## Check if all the files were correctly copied
if [[ -z "$badfiles" ]]; then
        echo "All files were succesfuly copied."
else
        printf 'Some files were not copied:\n%s\n' "$badfiles"
fi
```

This will fail if the file names in your csv can contain newlines. If that is a possibility, change the first `while` loop to:

```
while IFS= read -d"," -r file rest; do ...
```

Note, however, that this will fail if any line of the csv contains nothing but a file name (so no comma). You can't have it both ways, if you can have lines with no commas use the 1st version and if you can have file names with newlines, use the second.

Comment: Thanks terdon, the only issue with this is that there are 4000+files and as the error is printed after each copy, it would be difficult for me to monitor if one of the files was not located. I will update my question to include the fact that I would like a fail summary at the end, rather than after each copy action.

Comment: @bms9nmh OK, that's easy enough. Give me a second to edit. Also note that I had an bug in the original version and the message was printed for files that _were_ copied, not those that weren't. And is having the same file name a potential problem?

Comment: ok thanks for that i'll wait and see your edit, I'm not 100% sure about the same name issue, its definitely a possibility though now you mention it.

Comment: @bms9nmh OK, the simplest solution would be to use `cp -i` (assuming you're on a Linux system or have access to GNU `cp`) which will prompt you before overwriting. That, however, means that you will have to interact with the script. If that's an issue, I can make it so that it will move `file` to `file1`, then `file2` etc. What do you prefer?

Comment: @bms9nmh I went with the version that increments the file name.

Comment: Worked perfectly terdon, the fake file I created is reported at the end. Thanks for that.

Comment: Can you explain something from the code fro me so I better understand it,  I would like to know how the  [[ -e "$destfolder/$file" ]]  bit works? thanks

Comment: @bms9nmh see `help test`. The `[[ -e foo ]]` and `[ -e foo ]` constructs return true if a file called `foo` exists. The general `[[ test ]] || command` will run `command` if `test` fails.

Comment: One thing I am currently stumped on is the script doesn't seem to copy a handful of files out of the 4000+. The permissions and owner of the files and folders they are in are the same as the others, and other files have been successfully copied from the same folders. Even more strangely the script doesn't report that the files weren't copied (i.e. it reports success). The filenames don't look unusual to me- example files:

Comment: Billy Bunter_TX_09_09_1956_LCH9311A.mp4        bap_02_08_2486_animal_magic.mp4      Tomorrows World_TX_01_04_1976_LSF1056Y.mp4

Comment: @bms9nmh please post a new question, linking back to this one, and show the _exact_ script you're running and an example of a file name that fails. Could these file names be on a line by themselves, with no comma, for example?

Comment: ok, i'm about to leave, but I'll create another question when I get chance, cheers.

Comment: @bms9nmh you can also ping me in [/dev/chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) if you like.

Comment: Hi terdon, I've created a new query for this here      http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267602/csv-copyscript-not-copying-5-files-out-of-4000

Answer (score 1):

1. Your loop is incorrect, since you do nothing with `rest`
2. As [terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22222/terdon) suggested, check after each copy, instead of once after loop
3. Negate the existence of file check, for correct comment
4. And heed [terdon's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22222/terdon) warning, if you have same named files in your source tree, you will only get one copy in destination.

Try this,

```bash
while read -d, -r file
do
   find $sourcefolder -name "${file}" -exec cp '{}' $destfolder \;
   ## Check if the file was copied
   [[ ! -e "$destfolder/$file" ]] && echo "File $file was not copied"
done < "$csv"
echo "Finished"
```

Update:

This solution works if your CSV is like this

```
fileA,fileB,fileC,fileD, ...
```

However since you say terdon's solution works your file must look like this

```
fileA,valueA1,valueA2,valueA3
fileB,valueB1,valueB2,valueB3
fileC,valueC1,valueC2,valueC3
fileD,valueD1,valueC2,valueD3
```

and the remainder of line after filename is simply discarded.